# Mocha/Should 'undefined is not a function'

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, should.js

I'm going off of [this](https://thewayofcode.wordpress.com/2013/04/21/how-to-build-and-test-rest-api-with-nodejs-express-mocha/) tutorial, trying to make tests with Mocha, Supertest, and Should.js.

I have the following basic test to create a user through a `PUT` endpoint that accepts it's data in headers.

```
describe('User Routes', function () {
    it('should allow me to make my user', function (done) {
        request(url)
        .put('/users')
        .set(myCreds)
        // end handles the response
        .end(function(err, res) {
              if (err) {
                throw err;
              }
              // this is should.js syntax, very clear
              res.should.have.status(201);
              done();
            });
        });
```

However, while the endpoint does trigger, and the user does get made, the code throws an error that `should` is undefined... `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`.

I have

```
var should = require('should');
var assert = require('assert');
var request = require('supertest');
```

At the top of the file, so why would it be undefined?

Comment: 1.) Just to rule that out, are you sure you have installed the `require`d packages?
(`npm install --save-dev should assert supertest`)
2.) What is the value of `res` when the exception is thrown?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling should incorrectly, try this:

```
res.should.have.property('status', 201)
```

or

```
res.status.should.be.equal(201)
```

or

```
should.equal(res.status, 201)
```

or install [should-http](https://www.npmjs.com/package/should-http).

Comment: Ah okay, thanks. `should.not` have trusted the tutorial so much. Will accept when it lets me.